# Windows Phone 8 app crashes only after downloaded from the store

Tags: c++, crash, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, windows-store

Our app has passed review, and our own internal testing with no major issues recognized, however when downloaded from the store, always crashes in a particular spot.

It is quite difficult for us at the moment to get any crash logs, so at this point I am just wondering if anyone else has had a similar issue and what was happening?

The app is a native C++ DirectX project using the FMOD library for audio as well as SQLite for Windows Phone 8.

Comment: The two main reasons for crashing after publication are localization (issues with parsing decimal numbers usually) and missing capabilities from the manifest file. Do you use any capability at the crash spot that you didn't use previously in the application? (Playing a sound, a video, accessing the GPS, using the sensors, using the microphone, ...)

Comment: I can't think of any that wouldn't have been used prior to the crash point. SQLite and FMOD are both used prior the crash but also at the crash.

Comment: Anyone got any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to test your app from store on different devices and with different culture/language settings. It's a common bug when parsing from file fails because of different delimiters, DateTime format, etc.
Another common reason - missing capabilities in manifest.
Third reason, thas was causing problems to lot of apps - they try to download something from Internet during the first start, but the connection is not available.
And because you mentioned you have native DirectX app, try to test your app compiled in a same way it's deployed from store. Sadly I can't find the link how to do it right now...
Edit: found it:
[How to test the retail version of your app for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj585401%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: The last point is interesting, if we compile an app, does it somehow change post deployment? If you find the information let me know!

Comment: I've found the link. Try to test your app according to it and let me know, if you run into any problems.

Comment: Have you found why your application crashes? I am currently facing exactly the same problem.